# TOST on mediation result

Tags: r, regression, mediation, equivalence, tost

Dear people of the internet

I have made a mediation test on a multiple linear regression and it comes out insignificant. However, I am having trouble trying to make a TOST equivalence test of the result.

Can I save the ACME result as a statistical model, so I can use the "equivalence_test" function? Or is there some way to figure out the mean and standard deviation of ACME, so i can use the TOSTER-package/calculate it manually?

For the mediation test, I use the mediation package and function of the same name.

EDIT: The mediator, independent variable and the dependent variable are all indexex made from PCA components. Therefore, the results have no immediate practical meaning or effect.

[image: Result of the mediation analysis]

Comment: Can't help with the code, but note that also a TOST will never tell you that "the H0 is truly true". The best it can tell you is that parameter values too far away from the H0 are incompatible with the data.

Comment: Yes, it is not a optimale way of phrasing it. I'll edit it. :)

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).